# gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect to host

Tags: 10.04, php

I am trying to upgrade my PHP version 5.3 to 5.4 but it is throwing the error

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS - the Lucid Lynx

Please help me to resolve this

```
root@shanmugam-desktop:~# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable   
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmplauYSt/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmplauYSt/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key E5267A6C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect to host
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
recv failed
```

Comment: I need to resolve this error `gpg: requesting key E5267A6C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect to host`

Comment: No, you need to resolve the previous one, the one refering to the sudo error. Since sudo is failing, gpg is not working.

Comment: Host name issue is fixed i updated my machine name. How to resolve this error `gpg: requesting key E5267A6C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect to host`